# probability of patient infected while medical test orgnized in Refugee camp

Tags: probability

> A medical test has been applied in refugee camp:
>
> - The infection rate was $20\ \%$.
> - What is the probability that the twentieth patients tested will be the one with the third infection $?$.

What I try: Let $A$ be the event in which patient is infective one time. Then $\displaystyle\mathrm{P}\left(A\right) = 20/100 = 1/5 = 0.2$.

Here I am trying to solve it using Binomial probability

$$
\mathrm{P}\left(X = 3\right) =
\binom{15}{3}\ \left(0.2\right)^{3}\ \left(0.8\right)^{12}
$$

Can anyone please explain me is my process is right $?$. If not Then please explain me Right way. Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  In order for patient $\#20$ to be the third positive, you need patient $\#20$ to be positive and you need exactly two positives among the first $19$ patients.

Comment: Still i am facing problem . Can you please explain me in detail. Thanks

Comment: Question 1:  What is the probability that patient $\#20$ is infected?

Comment: Question 2; What is the probability that exactly two people out of $19$ are infected?

Comment: Maens we can say $\displaystyle P(X=2)=\binom{19}{2}\cdot (0.2)^{2}\cdot (0.8)^{17}$.

Comment: Above probability for exactly $2$ infected out of $19$ and probability for  patient #20 is infected is $(0.2)$

Comment: Don't write things like $P(X=2)$ unless you have defined your terms.  But, yes.  What you wrote is the probability that exactly two people out of the $19$ are infected.  And $.2$ is indeed the probability that $\#20$ is infected.  Since these events are independent, all you have to do now is multuiply.

Comment: Thanks so much .means final answer is $\displaystyle \binom{19}{2}\cdot (0.2)^3\cdot (0.8)^{17}$

Comment: That is correct.